# Convert String into bitvector in java

Tags: java, string, bitvector

I want to convert a string into its corresponding bitvector according to character bitvalue (user-specified). I am dealing with genome string, where i have only 4 characters i.e. A,G,C,T. I want to represent them with following bit-value in java

```
A = 01
G = 11
C = 10
T = 00
```

Now given a String "AGGT" then its corresponding bitvalue should be 01111100. I have tried doing it as follow:

```
 BitSet A = new BitSet(2);
 BitSet G = new BitSet(2);
 BitSet C = new BitSet(2);
 BitSet T = new BitSet(2);
 A.set(01);
 G.set(00);
 C.set(11);
 T.set(10);

String p = "AGGT";
BitSet bb = new BitSet();
for(int i = 0, n = p.length() ; i < n ; i++) { 
   bb.set(p.charAt(i))      
}
```

What am i doing wrong? How to do it in correct fashion.?

Comment: Do you want only the string representation or also the number?

Comment: You probably didn't read the JavaDoc on `BitSet`. As an example `A.set(01)` should be `A.set(1)`, i.e. you just set the bit at index 1 leaving the first bit at index 0 unset/0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Thomas, [`BitSet.set(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set(int)) doesn't work like you apparently expect it to.

> ```
> public void set(int bitIndex)
> ```
>
> Sets the bit at the specified index to true.

So: `G.set(00)` doesn't set the two bits of `G` to `0`: it sets the second bit (at position 1) of `G` to `true`.

But you don't then use the bitsets you initially create: if you encounter an `A` in the string, you are actually setting the 66-th bit (at position 65) to `true`, since 65 is the integer value of the char literal `'A'`.

---

The easiest way would just be to do a switch in the loop:

```
Bitset bb = new BitSet(2 * p.length());
for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); ++i) {
  switch (p.charAt(i)) {
    case 'A':
      bb.set(2*i + 0, false);
      bb.set(2*i + 1, true);
      break;
    case 'G':
      bb.set(2*i + 0, false);
      bb.set(2*i + 1, false);
      break;
    // etc.
  }
}
```

(Setting the bits to `false` isn't necessary; but it's just a bit more explicit).